# connect android application with mysql

Tags: android, mysql

I had uploaded a code for developing android app connected with mysql and php to learn from. from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
I've tried to do the same steps for more understanding. 
I've created a second table ( test ) in the same database .. and I wrote the php code for create a new raw in the ( test table ) ..
This is the php code  :

```
 <?php



// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES('$name', '$age')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "row successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

After that I added a java class in the eclipse project, following is the code:

```
package com.example.androidhive;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewRowActivity extends Activity{

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        EditText inputName;
        EditText inputAge;

        // url to create new row
        private static String url_create_raw = "http://10.0.2.2/test/create_row.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_raw);

            // Edit Text
            inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            inputAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);


            // Create button
            Button btnAddRow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

            // button click event
            btnAddRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // creating new product in background thread
                    new CreateNewRow().execute();
                }
            });
        }


        /**
         * Background Async Task to Create new product
         * */
        class CreateNewRow extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewRowActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Adding a raw ..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Adding raw
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String age = inputAge.getText().toString();


                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));


                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_raw,
                        "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreenActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

When the app is running in the emulator it doesn't work ! And the emulator stopped.

Any solution ?

Comment: post log also when app is crashing and also move all UI related code from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your Android Manifest for this sample app, so that it has permission to access the internet? If you haven't already done so, you'll need to add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

....somewhere outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit out of the norm.Why don't you just form a class/method to connect with the php script which you can then call it later?This is a way better approach.

Comment: this is my first time to program for android, i just follow the steps in the tutorial link .. setup my mysql database , code my php api and then code my android program  ! 
in fact I can't get what you mean :(